# A differentiable manifold class $C^k$ but not class $C^{k+1}$

Tags: differential-topology

Please show that the graph of $f(x)=|x|^λ$, where $k<λ<k+1$ is a differentiable manifold of class $C^k$ but not class $C^{k+1}$. (Problem in Differential Topology,  Hirsch, Morris W.)
Or, please show other examples.

Comment: Which part confuses you? Why the graph of a $C^k$ map is a $C^k$-submanifold, or why that function is a $C^k$ map for $\lambda <k<\lambda +1$? Or maybe both?

Comment: I cannot understand the reason why the graph of $f(x)=|x|^\lambda$ is not a  $C^{k+1}$-submanifold.